# Bellman ford performance

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, shortest-path, bellman-ford

```
   for(int k=1; k<=Vertices-1; k++){   
        /*Every sublist has found the shortest to its adjacent vertices
        thats why starting loop from k-1 then going into every edge of a vertex
        and updating the shortest distance from it to the other.
        */
        for(int i=k-1; i<Vertices; i++){
            // Visiting every Vertex(V) and checking distance of its edges to some other vertex Vo.
            for(int j=0; j<Edges[i].size(); j++){
                int v = Edges[i].get(j).src;
                int edge = Edges[i].get(j).dest;
                int weight = Edges[i].get(j).weight;
                // if exisiting distance is not infinity and from source to that vertex the weight is less then update it
                if (dist[v]!=Integer.MAX_VALUE && dist[v]+weight<dist[edge]){
                    dist[edge]=dist[v]+weight;
                    //updating parent of destination to source.
                    parent[edge] = v;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have implemented bellman ford from list of (LinkedList) as the algorithm runs V-1(loop 1) times and going into every vertex(in Loop2) it checks all of it edges(in loop3) and update the distances of destinations.I'm confused here that the time complexity will still be O(VE) or changed,I have seen this work done in 2 loops thats why, and also will the shortest path be found for each vertex passing by or i have to start it from 0?

Comment: Consider adding more details to this post, it will improve the likelihood of you getting quality answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you are checking all the edges for V time, the complexity is still `O(VE)`. for further information read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).

Comment: So i should set second loop to 0 to reach each V times right?

Comment: @SajUsman if you are about to change the complexity, the total complexity won't be lesser than O(VE). Suppose you have 2 loop each iterating over n, the complexity would be O(n^2). Now imagine that the inner loop goes 1,2,...n times. Computing this sum (1+2+...n) will results to n(n+1)/2 which is also O(n^2).

Comment: ahh now i get it it will always run for n times and thus after removing constants we will still get n times of complexity